# List of custom object data retrieval in Javers

Tags: javers

I have an object with attributes like below:

```
public class Model1 {
   private String aa;
   private List<String> bb;
   private List<CC> list;
}
```

```
public class CC{
   private String cc1;
   private List<String> cc2;

}
```

When I use javers, I am able to get changes made to `aa` and `bb`. But for `List<CC>` it just says, `list/2` was added or `list/0` was removed but it does not give exact data that was added or removed.

How do I get the complete data of CC object which was added, removed or changed from list?

Comment: What's CC type?

Comment: it is a custom object.

Comment: Your question is unclear